# Find smallest plan (timeout)

Tags: python, algorithm

I solved this algorithm, but some of them got timeout.
I tried to use binary search to make the code effective but still got timeout.
Cloud you tell me how can I fix this? Or let me know my approach is wrong?

Thank you so much.

**Question**
When prospective customers are planning to sign up for A Telecom, and they know the data and additional services they want to use, the smallest plan number that provides at least the amount of data they want to use and includes all the additional services they want is compiled into a list for each customer. If there is no plan that meets these conditions, a 0 is included in the list.

Here's an example where there are three types of plans, five types of additional services, and four prospective customers looking to sign up.

plan

| plan | data | additional service | added additional service |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1,3 | 1,3 |
| 2 | 500 | 1,3,4 | 4 |
| 3 | 2000 | 1,3,4,5 | 5 |

customers

| data to use | additional service to use |
| --- | --- |
| 300 | 3,5 |
| 1500 | 1 |
| 100 | 1,3 |
| 50 | 1,2 |

- The first customer can be provided with all the services they want to use if they choose Plan 3. Plan 2 cannot be selected because it does not provide the additional service 5 that the first customer wants to use.
- The second customer can be provided with all the services they want to use if they choose Plan 3. Plan 2 cannot be selected because it does not provide enough data.
- The third customer can be provided with all the services they want to use if they choose Plan 1.
- Since there is no plan that provides the additional service 2 that the fourth customer wants to use, a 0 is included in the list.

Therefore, the list of smallest plan numbers that can provide each customer with the services they want to use is [3,3,1,0].

Input Example

| n | plans | client | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | ["100 1 3", "500 4", "2000 5"] | ["300 3 5", "1500 1", "100 1 3", "50 1 2"] | [3,3,1,0] |

**My Answer**

```
def solution(n, plans, clients):
    plan_list = []
    for idx, plan in enumerate(plans):
        data, *services = map(int, plan.split())
        services.sort()
        if idx > 0:
            services = sorted(list(set(services).union(set(plan_list[idx-1][1]))))
        plan_list.append((data, services))

    plan_list.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1][-1] if x[1] else 0))

    answer = []
    for client in clients:
        client_data, *client_services = map(int, client.split())
        client_services_set = set(client_services)
        client_services_set.discard(0)

        left, right = 0, len(plan_list) - 1
        selected_plan = 0

        while left <= right:
            mid = (left + right) // 2
            plan_data, plan_services = plan_list[mid]

            if plan_data >= client_data:
                if set(plan_services).issuperset(client_services_set):
                    selected_plan = mid + 1
                    right = mid - 1
                else:
                    left = mid + 1
            else:
                left = mid + 1

        answer.append(selected_plan)

    return answer
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with binary search - that's perhaps the optimal approach. I think the main problem is maintaining services as a list instead of a set, subsequently converting it to a set on each comparison. So, the main improvement I'd do is to keep services as a set.

On the implementation style, I'd just piggiback on built-in `bisect` instead of writing my own binary search. Using a `NamedTuple` is not required but improves readability quite a bit:

```
import bisect
import itertools
from typing import NamedTuple, Set

# not required, just for readability
class Plan(NamedTuple):
    data: int
    services: Set[int]

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Plan(max(self.data, other.data), self.services.union(other.services))

    def __lt__(plan, client):
        return plan.data < client.data or not plan.services.issuperset(client.services)


def solution(n, plans, clients):
    plan_list = []
    for plan in plans:
        data, *services = map(int, plan.split())
        plan_list.append(Plan(data, set(services)))
    plan_list.sort(key=lambda plan: (plan.data, max(plan.services, default=0)))
    plan_list = list(itertools.accumulate(plan_list, initial=Plan(0, set())))

    answer = []
    for client in clients:
        client_data, *client_services = map(int, client.split())
        idx = bisect.bisect_left(plan_list, Plan(client_data, set(client_services)))
        answer.append(0 if idx > len(plans) else idx)

    return answer
```